# Finding python source internals

Tags: python, debugging

I like to read the source of src.**contains**().
As src is a python built-in class and it is open source I think it is available for inspection. I can see the definition in builtins.pyi. For the source I downloaded : git clone https://github.com/python/cpython/ and searched for "class src(", I found nothing. In cpython/Lib/string.py I see a reference to "import _string" but again I am unable to find _string.py. Can you explain to me the procedure I have to follow to find a class implementation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check out the python documentation:https://docs.python.org/3.10/
That's usually the first and best place to look up something related to a package or program.

This link https://docs.python.org/3.10/py-modindex.html redirects you to the bultin modules of python. When you click on one of them you will see a link to the source code beneath the header.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are digging the cpython source code, you must be familiar with python。

we can get the answer like this, in **ipython**:

In [1]: import _string

In [2]: dir(_string)

Out[2]:
['**doc**',
'**loader**',
'**name**',
'**package**',
'**spec**',
'formatter_field_name_split',
'formatter_parser']

In [3]: _string.**package**

Out[3]: ''

In [4]: _string.**loader**

Out[4]: _frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter

At this time，we can see this **_string** module came from BuiltinImporter

And  There is method called  **formatter_field_name_split**, search this name in the project you will find that in **Objects/unicodeobject.c**

At the end of this file ,you `ll get all you want